# how to concat a variable to a regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, concatenation

I am trying to concat a variable to a regen in c# but it is not working

```
string color_id = "sdsdssd";
Match variations = Regex.Match (data, @""+color_id+"_[^\""]*\""\W\,\""sizes\""\:\s*\W.*?businessCatalogItemId"":\"")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);@""+color_id+"_[^\""]*\""\W\,\""sizes\""\:\s*\W.*?businessCatalogItemId"":\"")";
```

But the above is not working

How to concat a variable at starting element to regex in c#

Comment: It’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. What is your desired result?

Comment: i want this "sdsdssd" to inserted in the place of color_id

Comment: Please do not re-post [one and the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386826/using-variables-in-regular-expression-c). See the answers below. I have tested [my code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38377195/3832970) against a fake `"sdsdssd_dddd\" ,\"sizes\": dbusinessCatalogItemId\":\""` string. Please provide yours and expected output.

Comment: Looks like the efforts have been abandoned.

Answer (score 3):

The `@` identifier only affects the immediately following literal string - you need to apply it to each string that needs it:

```
Match variations = Regex.Match (data,color_id +                     
                                     @"_[^\""]*\""\W\,\""sizes\""\:\s*\W.*?businessCatalogItemId"":\"")", 
                                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: error parsing 'sdsdssd_[^\"]*\"\W\,\"sizes\"\:\s*\W.*?businessCatalogItemId":\")' - Too many )'s.

Comment: But a verbatim string literal does not have you overescape the pattern, use `Regex.Escape(color_id) + @"_[^""]*""\W,""sizes"":\s*\W.*?businessCatalogItemId"":"""` (`Regex.Escape()` might be redundant if the variables never contain non-alphanumeric symbols)

Comment: It's hard to distinguish what is code and what is data in your string, or what quotes you are trying to escape - I tried to make assumptions based on what you posted but may have gotten it wrong.  The point is that `@` only applies to the literal string that immediately follows it, so `@"string1" + b + "string2"` does not apply the `@` to `string2`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you appear to have put this into your code twice.

@""+color_id+"_[^\""]*\""\W\,\""sizes\"":\s*\W.*?businessCatalogItemId"":\"")"

Removing that should allow the concatenation to work.

Alternatively, you could use String.Format to make the pattern

```
string pattern = String.Format("@{0}_[^\""]*\""\W\,\""sizes\""\:\s*\W.*?businessCatalogItemId"":\"")", color_id)
Match variations = Regex.Match (data, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

In the String.Format, it will replace the {0} with color_id. You can use this to insert multiple variable into the string. [Take a look at this MSDN page for more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)